AWS for executing automated tests with selenium + java doesn't fill fileds with sendKeys command
I'm using AWS to execute automated regression tests with Selenium and Java. I've encountered an issue where, on some forms, the fields are not being populated with text after the sendKeys() command. This issue does not occur when I run the tests on my local machine. Has anyone experienced this before, and how did you solve it?
I also try to to complete fields with JS executor:
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='4646464646464644';", adyenCardNumber);

This populates the fields, but the form is not validated after clicking submit buuton.
